# How to assign a unique identifier to a Websocket

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Using socket.ioin a Node/Express environment, is it possible to uniquely assign, say someone's login id, when a socket connection is made?

### Updated

Within my app.js (express) file, I have the following code to access the login, from the request headers:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next){        
  let login = req.header('login');
  next();
});
```

I need a means of being able to broadcast messages using this unique identifier (login) via socket.io

Comment: It's not hard to assign a property to a webSocket object.  It's not hard to keep a Map object with all the currently webSocket objects indexed by userID they belong to.  What we don't know from your environment is how you associate the right userID with a new incoming webSocket connection.  That you'd have to show us and then I could show you the rest of the code as a complete set.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the reply. I'm new to websockets and I guess what you are asking me is basically what I am trying to achieve.My thinking is that when a "io.on('connection', (socket) => {" call is made, I have the login id when the user fires up the browser app. Unsure if I am missing something.

Comment: Are you using socket.io or plain webSocket (you have indications of both in your question and socket.io would make things easier)?  Does your user already authenticate in your web page and use a cookie to maintain that logged in state?

Comment: @jfriend00 Apologies. I am using socket.io and have updated my original post. Correct on the other question you asked - yes, user is already authenticated and cookie use. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll assume that you have the ability to figure out which user it is from the login cookie.  Since you don't show us how you set up the cookie, you will have to write your own code to do that.

When a socket.io `connection` event occurs, you can get to the cookies from the initial socket.io connection request in `socket.request.headers.cookie`.  Let's assume you have a function named `getUserFromCookie()` that you pass a login cookie to and it returns the userID and we'll assume your login cookie is named "login".  Then, you could write code like this:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    let userId = getUserFromCookie(socket.request.headers.cookie);
    // join user to a room with the name of their userId
    socket.join(userId);
});
```

Then, elsewhere in your server code where you want to send a message to a particular `userId`, you can do it by just doing this:

```
io.to(userId).emit("someMsg", someData);
```

Comment: With the user id, I actually have this set using sessionStorage and apologies, it's actually not using cookies to store the logged in user. With the means that you have suggested above, to obtain the user, the user id value is available as part of the Request Headers. Is there a means of obtaining this value using socket.io?

Comment: @tonyf - You can get access to your session from socket.io.  You'd have to show more about your session code to know what to suggest.

Comment: instead of your let user code, it would read let userId = sessionStorage.getItem('login'); BTW, just to confirm, is your io.on connection code on the server or client - I'm assuming it's on the server - correct?

Comment: @tonyf - Yes, this code is on the server.  Yes, you would get the userID from your session object.  You will need to work out how to get the session object from inside of socket.io.  If you're using express-session for your session management, you can probably use something like this [express-session-socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session).

Comment: I just had a quick look at your express-session link but unsure how to access the session storage as the userid is set at startup within an angular 5 js file. Will investigate further.

Comment: @tonyf - As I said earlier, we can't help you with ANY session code unless you add your session code to your question so we can see what you have already.  Can't help what we can't see.

Comment: Have updated my original post to show you how I currently access the login within my app.js file, via requst headers. Based on this, how can I now access and assign this login from express to socket.io to be able to only broadcast messages to specific login ids based on your answer?

Comment: @tonyf - That code doesn't make any sense to me.  You declare a local variable called `login` that gets the value of request header and then you never use it and then it goes out of scope when you call `next()`.  There's no server-side session shown there at all.  You can easily get access to that same `login` header from socket.io if that's what you're trying to do with `socket.request.headers.login`, but I don't see how you can trust a header as your login.

Comment: Appreciate your help on the "socket.request.headers.login". FYI, the user is authenticated and header info set otherwise they would receive a connection refusal.With the broadcasting of messages and specifically on the client side, for a specified user/login to be listening for their own messages, each authenticated user, accessing the website will have their own socket connection against their login - 1) will this login be associated against a unique socket id on the server? 2) on the client side, is the code simply "socket.on('message',....)" where message is the eventName?